# Find coordinates of extended line segment intersects with given longitude

Tags: coordinate-system, c#, line, spherical-geometry

I have a line between C1 and C2;

[image]

My Coordinates are;

C1: 36.454N - 21.785E
C2: 41.725N - 38.475E

I want to find C3 latitude value based on given longitude when I extend my C1-C2 line segment.

IE C3 Lng is 42.00E.

How can I find it? And I use EPSG:4326 as CRS.

Comment: Are you using a specific GIS software, or is this a theoretical question?

Comment: I am using DotSpatial nuget package in my net.core project, but i will implement the theory in c#

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The answer is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2862455/pull-constant-from-atan2-function)

```
tan(c3Lat) = tan(MaxLat) * cos(c3Lon-c2Lon);
```